# MediaStream turns off when record and play on same video tag

Tags: javascript, angular, webrtc, getusermedia

I am creating an app where user can record and play there video. I am doing it in same video tag to stream and play the recorded video but I am having issue when I start the recording thrid time. For th first time when I start record and stop then play the video its works fine and when do again it works fine but when so it one more time the media stream stop and I get error `DOMException: Failed to execute 'start' on 'MediaRecorder': There was an error starting the MediaRecorder`. I am not able to understand why its not working on third time. Please if someone can help me out finding the issue.
This is my code.
Start Camera

```
startCamera(): void {
   
    this.videoElement.play();
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: {
          echoCancellation: {exact: true}
        },
      })
      .then((stream) => {
        this.videoStream = stream;
        this.addStream();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
      });
  }
```

Adding Stream to video tag

```
private addStream(): void {
    this.videoElement.srcObject = this.videoStream;
  }
```

Start Record
record(): void {

```
    if (this.videoElement.srcObject === null) {
      this.videoElement.removeAttribute('src')
      this.addStream();
      this.videoElement.play();
    }
    const sUsrAg = navigator.userAgent;
    if (sUsrAg.indexOf('Firefox') > -1) {
      this.videoElement.mozCaptureStream();
      this.startRecordingMedia(this.videoElement.mozCaptureStream());
    } else { 
      this.startRecordingMedia(this.videoElement.captureStream());
    }
  }
private startRecordingMedia(stream: MediaStream): void {
    try {
      this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      const data = [];
      this.recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => data.push(event.data);
      this.recorder.onerror = (event) => {
        console.log(event);
      };
      this.recorder.start();
      this.recorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
        console.log('stopped')
      });
 
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
     
    }
  }
```

Stop Recording

```
this.videoElement.pause();
    this.recorder.stop();
    this.videoElement.srcObject = null;
    const recordedBlob = new Blob(data);
    this.videoElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait that your `<video>` actually started playing before recording the MediaStream captured from it. At the time you call `MediaRecorder.start()`, the `this.videoElement.play();` Promise still hasn't resolved, and nothing is in the MediaStream, hence the MediaRecorder can't produce correct data.

So you could simply await that call to `play()`, but there is absolutely no point in even capturing the MediaStream again from the `<video>`, instead record directly the MediaStream you have from the camera (stored in `this.stream`), you'll save trees.